# symfony 1.4 forms: Using <p> rather than <li>

Tags: symfony-1.4

When calling a form using

```
print $widget->render()
```

rather than printing

```
<li>
       <label ...>
       <input ...>
</li>
```

How can I have it print

```
<p>
    <label ...>
    <input ...>
</p>
```

PS:  in my form:

```
public function configure()
{
    $this->widgetSchema->setFormFormatterName('list');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to create your own form schema formatter class as explained [here](http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/06-Advanced-Forms#chapter_06_custom_styling_when_a_form_element_has_an_error). For example, to use a paragraph you can just redeclare the $rowFormat variable:

```
#lib/widget/sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatterParagraph.class.php

class sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatterParagraph extends sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatter
{
    protected $rowFormat = "<p>
                         %label% \n %error% <br/> %field%
                         %help% %hidden_fields%\n</p>\n";
}
```

If you want to use this format for all forms of your project add it to your ProjectConfiguration class (and remove the $this->widgetSchema->setFormFormatterName('list') from your form):

```
class ProjectConfiguration extends sfProjectConfiguration
{
    public function setup()
    {
      // ...

      sfWidgetFormSchema::setDefaultFormFormatterName('paragraph');
    }
 }
```

If you want to use it only for one form, add this your form class:

```
    public function setup()
    {
         $this->widgetSchema->addFormFormatter('paragraph', new sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatterParagraph($this->widgetSchema));
         $this->widgetSchema->setFormFormatterName('paragraph');
         parent::setup();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just look at `sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatterList`and `sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatter.class.php`. You can make your own schema from that, let's say `sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatterParagraph`, and change the properties of the class to match your needs. (you probably need to change only `$decoratorFormat` and `$rowFormat`. Something like:

```
$rowFormat = "<p> %error%%label%\n  %field%%help%\n%hidden_fields%</p>"
$decoratorFormat = "%content%"
```